# How to create an option under "Open With" option when i right click on a file?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing a RCP application that creates and shows chart. I have already developed the chart creation part. So now my goal is to when my runtime eclipse starts the **package explorer** already has the **.csv** file based on which i am creating chart. Now i want to right click on the .csv file and "Open with" should have an option called "ChartView" that on click will create a view with the chart which defines the selected file.

So how can i create a new option in **"Open With"** category that will create a new view on click. I tried to search this issue but unfortunately did not find any clue. Please help. Thanks

Comment: That list is only shows editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "**Open With**" category is populated by the list of Editors that say they can open the file. You add an editor using the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point.

http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_editors.html?cp=2_1_1_147